# Is it possible to stretch individual sides of a div in CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigation, stretch

I have a navigation bar that I'd like to stretch to the full width of the browser. Is it possible to stretch only the top, right & left sides of this div so they touch the sides of the browser?
Here is my code right now: 
HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
    <a href="index.html"><li>Home</a></li>
    <a href="about.html"><li>About</a></li>
    <a href="contact.html"><li>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #B4ABAB;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2.5px grey;
}
.navigation li {
    float: left;
}
.navigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

I have tried the background-size property and set it to 100% but it has no effect plus I can't edit individual sides with that. I have also tried verticle-align: middle; however, it's not working either. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please include a picture or some visual example of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the html and body tags to reflect that you want a margin of 0.

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

By default, your browser has internal stylization that can (and should) be neutralized.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lphggzf6/

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm surprised I didn't even think of that lol

Answer (score 0):

```
.navigator {
    position : fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

probably you should keep your navigator fixed and scrollable content within it.